# How to access 'layout' or 'page' function directly in component?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How can I access a layout- or page-function directly in a component? Is there a special variable like `$root` or `$parent`?

[image: structure]

I found a way to do this, but it seems dirty. I saw the component structure using Vue DevTool, and I found the layout is the root's child, so I called the layout's function like this:

```js
this.$root.$children[2].getMap()
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Sounds like a good case for having centralised state management ~ https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: @Phil First, Thank you for your response. as you said I considered using vuex store. but, This object is so big. so I thought using vuex can make loss...
for Example, you init google map object and assign to variable. Is it right to share variable via vuex?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is for... distributing state amongst otherwise disconnected components

Answer (score 0):

You could use Vue's [`provide`/`inject`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) feature for this. For instance, a page/layout could `provide` the `getMap()`:

```html
<template>
  <MapButton />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MapPage',
  provide() {
    return {
      getMap() {
        return { /* map */ }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

...and then any child component on that page/layout could `inject` the method where needed:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="getMap">Get map</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MapButton',
  inject: {
    getMap: {
      default() {
        return () => {
          console.log('no map')
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('map', this.getMap())
  }
}
</script>
```